# keras RNN w/ local support and shared weights

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to understand how Keras sets up weights to be shared.  Specifically, I would like to use a convolutional 1D layer for processing a time-frequency representation of an audio signal and feed it into an RNN (perhaps a GRU layer) that has:

- local support (e.g. like the Conv1D layer with a specified kernel size).  Things that are far away in frequency from an output are unlikely to affect the output.
- Shared weights, that is I train only a single set of weights across all of the neurons in the RNN layer.  Similar inferences should work at lower or higher frequencies.

Essentially, I'm looking for many of the properties that we find in the 2D RNN layers.  I've been looking at some of the Keras source code for the convnets to try to understand how weight sharing is implemented, but when I see the weight allocation code in the layer build methods (e.g. in the _Conv class), it's not clear to me how the code is specifying that the weights for each filter are shared. Is this buried in the backend?  I see that the backend call is to a specific 1D, 2D, or 3D convolution.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you - Marie